# tinymce skin in IE 11 compatibility mode

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, tinymce, internet-explorer-11

I'm using newest version of tinymce (4.2.1), but whenever I switch to compatibility mode, my tinymce use skin.ie7.min.css instead of skin.min.css. It makes some icon disappear.

I tried compatibility mode in tinymce home page too but no different, skin.min.css is still in use.

This only happen on IE 11, IE 10 is working fine, does anyone know what's happening ?

Comment: Can you share your TinyMCE init code?

Comment: I even use the same init code as tinymce home page. but it still happen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had same problem, and fixed with this line:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
```